# Hide an element in a view just before to take a screen shot

Tags: ios, screenshot

I try to hide an element in a view just before to take a screen shot.

```
-(void)method{
  [self.element setHidden:YES];
  UIImage *image = [self screenShot];
}


- (UIImage *)screenShot {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, YES, 0);
  [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];
  UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return newImage;
}
```

But the element is on the screen shot image. How to force refreshing the view to hide the element in the screen shot ?
Thanks by advance.

Comment: How is screenshot implemented?

Comment: Pass `YES` to `afterScreenUpdates:` `A Boolean value that indicates whether the snapshot should be rendered after recent changes have been incorporated`

Comment: Shame on me... sorry for the inconvenience.
Happy new year !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` ensure that you take the snapshot after your updates have been applied by passing `YES` as the second argument